# Raising a number to the power of a range of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

The formula I would like to use looks something like this: SUMPRODUCT(x^(1:n),y^(n:1)). n=values in column A. 1:n is the exponents in forward progression from 1 to n in steps of 1. n:1 is the exponents in reverse progression from n to 1 in steps of 1. I would like the formula to be dynamic to fill in column B with the n values based on column A.

Comment: Note that you can write this in various ways, but only about the last 20 of the 100 values would contribute significantly to the total, because you are limited to about 15 figures of accuracy in Excel calculations.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated my end goal in the beginning. The formula I would like to use looks like this: SUMPRODUCT(x^(1:n),y^(n:1)). n=values in column A. 1:n is the exponents in forward progression from 1 to n in steps of 1. n:1 is the exponents in reverse progression from n to 1in steps of 1. @JvdV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(5^ROW(1:100))
```

Or in Excel O365

```
=SUM(5^ROW(1:100))
```

---

As per @RonRosenfeld, a more sturdy solution could be `=SUM(5^SEQUENCE(100))` in Excel 365.

---

***EDIT:** Based on OP's comments he could use (no O365):*

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(5^ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))),7^LARGE(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))),ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)))))
```

Comment: In Excel O365 you could also use `=SUM(5^SEQUENCE(100))`

Comment: Yup I know @RonRosenfeld, however, I was thinking Code Golf =)

Comment: Problem with the `ROW(...` approach is when some user inserts a row.

Comment: SUMPRODUCT(5^ROW(1:100)) worked GREAT for the question asked.  Thank you for taking the time.  I should have just asked the full question in the first place.  I need the 100 value to be dynamic based on a cell value in a range of cells.  I would also like to see if the exponents could run in the SUMPRODUCT function in reverse.  My example above is SUMPRODUCT(x^(1:n),y^(n:1)).  That is my MAIN goal.  If you could make this happen with a simple formula that would be AMAZING!  Thank you again for taking the time to do this!!!

Comment: @JohnHenryJr., It may be a better idea to clarify what you are after in the original post. Edit in some examples, even a screenshot could help to clarify what you are after. You can tag me back when you are done and I'll make sure to look into it.

Comment: @ JvdV Sorry, I should have stated my end goal in the beginning. The formula I would like to use looks something like this: SUMPRODUCT(x^(1:n),y^(n:1)). n=values in column A. 1:n is the exponents in forward progression from 1 to n in steps of 1. n:1 is the exponents in reverse progression from n to 1 in steps of 1.

Comment: @JohnHenryJr. I meant you need to actually update your original post. Not comment underneath. There is an edit button. Anyways. I think I understood what you are after. See my updated answer.

Comment: @JvdV IT WORKED!!!  Thank you SOOOOO MUCH!!!!!  I greatly appreciate your time put into this!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can store the powers in a column and use the array formula:
`SUM((A1:A100)^$B$1)` where A column contains 5 in each cell and B column contains the range of powers you want to use. You can use an array formula in the different cell to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **SERIESSUM** function

The Excel SERIESSUM function returns the sum of a power series, based on the following power series expansion:

Power Series Equation

The syntax of the function is:

**SERIESSUM( x, n, m, coefficients )**

Where the function arguments are:

- **x** -   The input value to the power series.
- **n** -   The first power to which x is to be raised.
- **m** -   The step size that n is increased by, on each successive power of x.
- **coefficients**  -   An array of coefficients that multiply each successive power of x.

The number of values in the supplied coefficients array defines the number of terms in the power series. This is illustrated in the following examples.

**Example 1:**

In the spreadsheet below, the Excel Seriessum function is used to calculate the power series:

```
5^1 + 5^2 + 5^3 + 5^4 + 5^5

formula: =SERIESSUM( 5, 1, 1, {1,1,1,1,1} )

output = 3905
```

**Example 2:**

```
1 * 2^1 + 2 * 2^3 + 3 * 2^5 + 4 * 2^7 + 5 * 2^9

formula: =SERIESSUM( 2, 1, 2, {1,2,3,4,5} )

output = 3186
```

[image]

I hope this is of help.

Comment: I would also like to see if the exponents could run in the SUMPRODUCT function in reverse. My example above is SUMPRODUCT(x^(1:n),y^(n:1)).  This is my final goal.  I should have probably just said this in the first place.  Sorry for not just starting with this.  I GREATLY appreciate you taking the time to do this!!!!!  Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1):

An Alternative Answer again. I think the correct for your case :-)

Using the SERIESSUM function allows the use of different coefficients therefore the reason for the use of the coefficients in an array. But because the coefficients are the same then this is simply a geometric progression.

The following formula will do that for you:

```
=n+n*(n)^(1)*(1-(n)^c)/(1-n)

where "n" is the number (5) and "c" is the number of the series (100)
```

This becomes:

```
=5+5*(5)^(1)*(1-(5)^100)/(1-5)
```

Comment: Good spot to use a GP. You can simplify it right down to =5^101/4 in this particular case.

Comment: True. Pleased that you have now the fix to the issue.

Comment: This works great with a single exception!  I had to modify the formula to =n+n*(n)^(1)*(1-(n)^(c-1))/(1-n).  Now I would like to ask ONE MORE favor.  This works for the forward progression trough the exponents (1 to 100).  Now, can you make the formula work in reverse (100 to 1)?  I would like to calculate the SUMPRODUCT(x^(1 to 100),y^(100 to 1)).

Comment: The reason that your formula is the most appropriate us because I am trying to make the range of exponents dynamic.  The exponent will change based on a range of values.  For example, the first value may be 50 and the next may be 250 followed by 175.  I would like the exponent ranges to be from 1 to the range value.  Example: SUMPRODUCT(x^(1 to 50),y^(50 to 1)) in one cell and in the next cell SUMPRODUCT(x^(1 to 250),y^(250 to 1)) followed by SUMPRODUCT(x^(1 to 175),y^(175 to 1)) in the following cell.

Comment: It's still a GP isn't, ratio x/y?

Answer (score 1):

=SUMPRODUCT(5^ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))),7^LARGE(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))),ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)))))

This formula worked flawlessly!!!

Thank you @JvdV and everyone else for your efforts in helping me!  GREATLY APPRECIATED!